# Replacing old Common-io jar file in Weblogic lib folder with Latest version

Tags: upgrade, weblogic12c, apache-commons-io, weblog

We have replaced the Old commons-io-1.4 jar file with latest commons-io-2.13.0.jar. As we've used the same in my latest POI apache project. Post making those changes application seems to be working fine. Please suggest if that is okay to make changes Weblogic library Or will it make any impact on weblogic server or application which is deployed on weblogic.